# explicit or implicit key of encryption in c#

Tags: c#, security, encryption

i am planing to write a C# class library which will include my encryption algorithms like RC4, DES. These are single key encryption algorithms. 
Now i want the best secure decision to protect my key. Should i **put my key hardcoded inside the DLL** or should i **set my key from my external application** which uses the DLL? Which one do you think is more secure when you consider the decompling tools?
Loudly thinking:

- if the key is hardcoded in my security library and someone find the DLL and import it to his C# application, can he easly decode my chipper data?
- if the key is not hardcoded in my security library but is set from my external application, someone needs to decompile also my external application to find my key?

Setting the key values from my external application which will use the security DLL seems more secure to me. What do you think?
Thanks.

Comment: If you hardcode a key inside your DLL then you have just made a totally useless DLL. And why would you want to implement [crypto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx) yourself?

Comment: Everything you're considering is insecure. It's obscure at best. As an attacker I'd just put a breakpoint on your crypto function where it receives the key and wait until you present it on the silver tablet.

Comment: You should first describe what you're actually trying to do, and what your thread model is.

Comment: @Jon i have to implement my own security library because the clients which my application communicates uses these algorithms. And why do you think that hardcoded key inside a DLL makes a useless DLL?

Comment: @Fer: So you are going to use your own crypto and DES etc was just an example? If so, *stop immediately and read a good crypto book*.

Comment: @Jon i know DES is not secure anymore but i have to use it. Because my clients uses this logic for data sharing so i need to use DES

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I assume you mean threat model. And yes, you and Jon are correct. If you want security, don't implement your own crypto. Use existing, tested, peer-reviewed, secure libraries, and spend the time to understand the best practices.

Comment: @Fer: Because anyone with access to the DLL can read the key. **The whole point of encryption is to protect a large amount of data by using a small amount of secret data, the key.** The security of a cryptographic system is through security of the key. If you don't know these things, you absolutely should not be implementing your own cryptographic protection scheme. Stop, and hire an expert immediately.

Comment: @CodeInChaos what i actully trying to do is performing an encryption for datasharing with clients over TCP. The clients uses some kind of security algorithms like DES, RC4 so i need to implement it in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hard Coded Key**

If you include the shared/private key in the DLL, then anyone who has a copy of the DLL will have a copy of the key.  If your model is to share your application with multiple users, all users will have the same encryption key, and can decrypt anything encrypted by another user.  If your application is easily available, then you have to assume the attacker has the application (and therefore the key) as well.

It also means that all developers will have access to the production encryption key, since they have the source code.  QE will also have access, as they probably have access to the binary.  Either of these two insider groups will be able to decrypt anythign that your application protects for your customers.

Is this what you want?  It's generally a bad practice, but it's worse in some environments than others.  For example, if you're writing code to learn how to write crypto and nothing more, it probably doesn't matter - just make sure nobody else can use it :)  If you're writing a service, it's a bad practice and introduces risk, but it's not the worst thing you could do.  If you're writing something that will be shared to multiple customers, then you defeat the purpose of encrypting by including the key in the binary.

And it's not really that hard to generate random data (using a cryptographically strong random number generator), store it in a file, and use that file as your encryption key.  My recommendation is go with the separate key.

**Separate Key**

If you ship the key in a separate file, you eliminate all the risks introduced by shipping the key in the binary but you introduce others.  Or, stated differently, now that your crypto can do some good, you need to make sure you do it right or it'll still be useless.

The key needs to be generated using a cryptographically strong random number generator, so that it's not predictable.  The key needs to be stored securely - the whole path to the key file needs to be protected, and you should consider using a password protected store (like a keystore) to ensure that only users with the right password can access the key.  Of course, that last one depends upon your deployment model, and if you need unattended restart.  And the key needs to be used securely - constant order operations, don't act an encryption or decryption oracle, verify integrity of data before semantically parsing it, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. you mean that using a cryptographically strong random number generator to generate a random key and keep it a seperate file seems better. And i understand that using hardcoded key in the DLL is horrible. What is more, i will tell my clients to use random keys for datasharing. If they insist on using fixed key, i think my data will not be actually protected. Over TCP first i must generate a random key and send my client connected to me, then the client will decrypt my chiper data with that key and vice versa.

Comment: @fer: Also, be very careful of assuming risk on behalf of your clients.  Do you really want access to the secrets that your clients were trying to share only with each other?  Do you think your clients will *want* you to have such access?  You should consider telling your customers what is secure, why it's secure, and that they incur risk if they choose to do anything less.  And fully support secure modes insofar as your code can (like creating the key for the customer, or allowing them to upload their own).  Then it's the customer's responsibility if they intentionally do something insecure.

Comment: I should also mention: you should not write your own crypto algorithms.  Or rewrite existing crypto algorithms.  You should use an existing, well reviewed, well tested crypto library.  Even very tiny coding errors can introduce critical risk.

Comment: you are right. we must use standard protocols to ensure security with clients. I think the point is that clients make this encryption system just for a protocol, their purpose is not security i guess. As you said, i will mention about which methot is secure and it will be customers' responsibility